# how to set vim transparent on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: vim, ubuntu

i try to set vim(VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2) transparent via the right click setting menu, and it works.

But the background just show up the desktop, not the pdf or the browser which under it.

My enviroment:

- ubuntu 10.04
- vim 7.2

Is there anything about ubuntu GUI knowledge that i should know before i do such things?

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/questions/74114/semi-transparent-terminal

Comment: @Explosion Pills , yes!! the command really help me! It seems like i need to enable the compositing_manager of metacicty.Still do not know exactly the detail of such concepts=.=~Any,thank you!

Comment: @Explosion Pills , can you move your comment to the answer , so i can take it as the best answer and make this question solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gconftool-2 -s '/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager' --type bool true
```

Comment: This is a good solution , but now every time i do a tab switch , it takes more time to react. May the effect like shadow and transparency occupy more computer resource...